# Pandas, use apply method?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an excel file that looks like this:

```
 A                           B  C   D    E       F        G

run_1_clust_1.out:          GLU 2   HN  2.07    3851    -0.90   
                            GLY 1   HN  2.09    3196    -0.90
                                3   HN  2.05    3553    -0.90   
                                    HT1 2.12    2828    -0.91   
                                    HT2 2.05    3516    -0.90 
run_1_clust_2.out:          GLU 2   HN  2.12    1940    -0.90   
                            GLY 1   HN  2.33    4030    -0.90
                                3   HN  2.43    3994    -0.90   
                                    HT1 2.11    2833    -0.91   
                                    HT2 2.05    3242    -0.90
```

I would like to group the columns E, F and G by columns B, C and D. For an output that looks like this:

```
 run_1_clust_1.out:          GLY 1  HN  2.09    3196    -0.90
 run_1_clust_2.out:          GLY 1  HN  2.33    4030    -0.90     
 run_1_clust_1.out:          GLU 2  HN  2.07    3851    -0.90 
 run_1_clust_2.out:          GLU 2  HN  2.12    1940    -0.90
 run_1_clust_1.out:          GLY 3  HN  2.05    3553    -0.90
 run_1_clust_2.out:          GLY 3  HN  2.43    3994    -0.90
 run_1_clust_1.out:          GLY 3  HT1 2.12    2828    -0.91
 ....
```

I'm using pandas, but I'm not sure why I get the AttributeError telling me to use the 'apply' method.

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

xl = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df.columns = df[['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']]
df = df.groupby(['b','c','d'])
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")

writer.save()
```

Comment: `df = df.groupby(['b','c','d'])` this line is going to give you a DataFrameGroupBy object. Not a DataFrame object. So you can't write that to CSV. Depending on what you want to do with the remaining columns, you would need to define some sort of aggregate function for them

Comment: Can you please provide some code to reproduce this data? Also, if you are just looking to re-order your data, use `sort_values` instead of `groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The main differences are: I've specified a calculation to perform on grouping and reset index so that the output is a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

xl = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df.columns = df[['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']]

group_cols = ['b','c','d']
sum_cols = ['e', 'f', 'g']

df = df[group_cols+sum_cols].groupby(group_cols).sum().reset_index()
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I see how defining a variable with the columns I want to group enables the data frame to be written to the excel file. However, I don't need to sum columns e,f,g - without the summation, I haven't been able to group group_cols - any suggestions on why? I tried to remap group_cols with group_cols.apply(lambda x: x.to_excel) but that didn't work either.

Comment: why don't you just remove the sum columns before outputting?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but I have and I still get an Attribute Error directing me to try using the 'apply'. `df = df[group_cols+sum_cols].groupby(group_cols).reset_index()`